# constant enum value in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, enums, hql

I have got a working query, which I need to modify by filtering with constant enum value.

Now it looks this way:

```
public static final String venueQuery = 
       "select distinct v from package.Venue v "
        + "<some joins here> "
        + "WHERE v.venueType = package.enums.VenueType.VOUCHER_PROVIDER ";
```

Changing data this way causes

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token
```

Column definition is like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "venue_type")
private VenueType venueType;
```

Enum definition looks this way:

```
public enum VenueType {
    RESTAURANT, BAR, CAFE, FUN_CLUB, VOUCHER_PROVIDER
}
```

I am sure that other parts of query works fine, because after removing it, no exceptions are thrown.

Are there tricks for setting constant enum value in HQL query?

Comment: Have you tried a parameterized query? And passing an enum value as the parameter value?

Comment: yes, passing goes fine. But I use venueQuery for base query and extend it with additional ORDER BY or WHERE cause strings. So I want to avoid adding parameter to all derivative methods

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The preferred way would be to go about adding parameters to the query and pass the enum instance as the parameter value, but if you don't (or can't) make it a parameterized query, you can still do it with `String` concatenation like this:

```
public static final String venueQuery = 
   "select distinct v from package.Venue v "
    + "<some joins here> "
    + "WHERE v.venueType = '" + VenueType.VOUCHER_PROVIDER.name() +"'";
```

If you want it a compile time constant query `String`:

```
public static final String venueQuery = 
   "select distinct v from package.Venue v "
    + "<some joins here> "
    + "WHERE v.venueType = 'VOUCHER_PROVIDER'";
```

Comment: 10x for the approach, but generated string value from this solution will be close to provided string. My major issue is that provided string from me does **not work**, so your solution also will not work :(

Comment: I like the approach of avoid hardcoding class and value options, but it seems to be not possible for @Query annotation: the compiler tells me that "element is not a constant string"

Comment: Then in this case you have to put them in apostrophes, also most likely class name must not be included. Edited.

Comment: I need a const value, but calling a final method is a runtime expression -> Compile error

Comment: Then try to insert the enum instance name, but still leave out the package and use apostrophes.

Comment: Thank you. Here is what worked for me: "WHERE v.venueType <> 'VOUCHER_PROVIDER' ". Seems string enums must be treated as regular strings. Enum class must not be mentioned!

Comment: That's exactly what I suggested in my last comment (which you said didn't help). And this is exactly what my answer does/proposes.

Comment: Your answer before your edition is absolutely not correct. After the edition it is also not correct for my case - Query annotation value must be constant, and it is not. Adding enum instance name as suggested, also makes the answer incorrect. If you want to mark it as correct, please edit it as it works - as a constant expression.

Comment: You're right. Edited the question to add a compile time constant query string.

Comment: Hi @icza i have looked on the internet and this post is the closest to an answer i could get. But my problem is a bit different i have a string query line with paramters public static final String TEST_QUERY = "SELECT fin FROM FinantialTable as fin WHERE " +
   "(fin.debitCredit = ?2)";    DebitCredit being an ENUM, I am passing DebitCredit.DEBIT in parameter 2 but it does not give me the desired results  - no errors the reult is that it selects all records from fin table, i want all Debit records, any advice?

Comment: @OzmaTis Look into the db and see how the enum values are stored there. If they are numbers, try passing `DebitCredit.DEBIT.ordinal()`. If they are string values, also give a try passing `DebitCredit.DEBIT.name()`.

Comment: @icza In my DB, its varchar. and my Enum class, DebitCredit has a  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) got this error when i try to pass .name()  java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Enum

Comment: @icza Here is what works, I can pass DebitCredit.DEBIT.name() and inside the query i can use cast as string to check for matches!! And it works e.g "cast(fin.debitCredit as string) = ?1 "  -- Not sure if this is a proper solution but for now it looks like it works...